# Apache Server Slots, Memory, KeepAlive, PHP and SSL - how to speed up

Tags: php, linux, performance, apache, ssl

on a Debian web server (VPS) with good CPU, 6 GB RAM, and fast backbone Internet connection, I run a PHP application. PHP runs in "prefork" mode (incl. APC opcache), because whenever you search for PHP and the MPM worker, there are abundant warning regarding thread safety. The PHP application is quite large, so each server process requires about 20 to 30 MB RAM. There is sensible data processed by the application, therefore, all connections to the Apache server are SSL encrypted.

Typically, the application shows no or few images (about 1-3 files incl CSS and JS per request) and the users send a new request each 1 minute (30 sec. to 4 minutes, depeding on the user).

Recently, this application faced a big storm of user requests (that was planned, no DoS, about 2.500 concurrent users). While the CPU did fine (<50% use), my server ran quickly out of slots. The point is that - in prefork mode - each slot requires memory and the 6 GB are just enough for "MaxClients" about 200 slots).

Problem 1: According to Apache server-status, most slots were occupied "..reading..". Sometimes reading for 10 seconds and more, while PHP processing takes 0.1 to 2 seconds. Few data is sent by the users, so I guess that this actually is the SSL handshake. This, of course, occupies lots of slots (I also enabled and configured mod_reqtimeout to drop very slow clients and - according to http://unhandledexpression.com/2013/01/25/5-easy-tips-to-accelerate-ssl/ - used SSLHonorCipherOrder to use faster encryption ciphers, SSLCertificateChainFile is also transmitted).

Problem 2: If I enable KeepAlive (only 1 or 2 seconds) to reduce the SSL overhead, slots are kept open and, therefore, occupied twice as long, as PHP processing would require.

Problem 3: If I actually wanted to serve 2.500 users, **and** want to use KeepAlive to speed up SSL, I would require 2.500 slots. However, I won't have a machine with 32 GB RAM.

With enough users on the server, to test its limits, I were stuck with about 110 requests per second, about 50% CPU load on a quadcore system (max. 400%). Less req/sec if I (re-)enabled KeepAlive. 110 req/sec on a modern webserver - this seems ridiculous!  I cannot believe that this is actually what Apache, PHP and SSL can perform.

Is there a major fail in my thinking? Do I encounter a basic limitation of the prefork mode? Did I ignore the obvious? Is SSL acutually such a performance-eater? Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of that article about SSL performance. I don't think the handshake is responsible for the 8+ seconds on reads. You can get useful information by using http://www.webpagetest.org/ . The handshake is done when a request is marked as "connected".

My guess would be that the slow processing of the PHP app with a lot of concurrent users can make some users wait a lot more.

Here are some ideas to get better performance:

- I don't think the KeepAlive would be a good idea if each client does a request every minute.
- You could enable SSL session tickets to reduce the handshake overhead.
- MPM-Worker works fine for a lot of different setups, so I encourage you to try it out.
- caching will probably not help you if the clients recieve a different response every time.
- you should test PHP-FPM, that could speed up the PHP code.
- also, test APC, to cache precompiled PHP code.
- I don't know anything about the architecture of your app, but you could defer sending the results: get the data from the client, send an immediate answer ("processing data..." or something like that), process the data in a background process, then on the next request, send the calculated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The WebPageTest is done in 1.5 sec. (3 files) and actually the SSL handshakes only requires 0.4 sec - about the same as the "time to first byte" processing time. That is much less time "wasted" than keeping the connection alive for seconds... Very good to know! I already use (and love) APC - so, it seems I should make myself used to PHP-FPM and MPM-Worker. Thanks :)

Comment: PS: You do not have an idea, why some users are "..reading.." so long (if it is not the SSL handshake)? If I understand this status correctly, PHP processing has not even started at this point of time?!

Comment: It depends on the way your code works. The important thing is the "time to first byte". If your PHP code sends data right away, but it takes time downloading, then the PHP code is slow. If the connection doesn't spend much time between "time to first byte" and the end of donwload, then either the PHP is slow, either there are too many concurrent users (and some have to wait for their turn).
Check in your server logs how many users are served at the same time.